# Custom Domain for Google AppEngine Apps

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have been fooling around with Google App engine for few days, the question I wanted to ask was,

If i want to deploy the web app to custom domain does the server need to be hosted on Windows Server???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need a Windows server.  You just need to sign-up for [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html), then [add](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html) the application to the domain.  If this is all you are using Google Apps for, then the free version will be fine.

I think you might have some misunderstandings about [App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html).  With App Engine, your applications run *on Google's* servers, not yours.

Also, the I believe servers are Linux, not Windows.

If you are wanting to run your own servers 'using' App Engine Java check out [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/).

Comment: Ok..Thanks...So if I am signing up for a hosting (Domain & Webspace) there is no particular requirement needed to run Google Apps rite??.. I mean I can go for any webhosting service??

Comment: In your question you ask about Google App Engine (http://code.google.com/appengine/).  App Engine is not the same thing as Google Apps for Your Domain (http://www.google.com/a/).  App Engine is not just a webhosting service, it is a platform-as-a-service.  If you want to serve an application developed and deployed on Google App Engine's platform from a custom domain, then you need to sign up for Google Apps; otherwise you do not need to.